# retrieve app's author - jailbreak iOS 6

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6, jailbreak

How can I retrieve an app's author (or developer or publisher, etc) on a jailbroken iOS 6.x device? In iOS 4.x and 5.x, there was an `author` member in the `SBApplication` class. But in iOS 6.1 I now get an `NSUnknownKeyException` when requesting the author. A quick look at SBApplication.h from a iOS 6 class dump online didn't show anything promising (except `signerIdentity`, but that's something else). Is there any easy way to get this, without digging around in any `Info.plist` files?

Update: The `Info.plist` files actually don't contain this information either. The `iTunesMetadata.plist` file on the other hand does, but System/Cydia apps don't have this file.

Comment: Is it that difficult to read it from the app's info.plist file?  Why doesn't this work for you?

Comment: Actually the info.plist files don't seem to have this information either.

Comment: Well, the `CFBundleIdentifier` generally has the company name, like `com.mycompany.MyAppName`.  Not what you were looking for?

Comment: I guess that would be a good fallback, but I'd prefer the real thing if possible. I noticed the iTunesMetadata.plist has the author, but Cydia apps don't have this file.

Comment: You could use `NSTask` or `system()` to get information on Cydia apps.  Use those to issue a call like `dpkg -l` to list package names, and then `apt-cache show mypackname` will show you all the metadata in the app's DEBIAN `control` file.

Comment: Ok that looks good. If you want to answer, I'll accept--don't think anyone else will come up with something better anytime soon.

Comment: What's with the votes to close? Specific feedback please!

Comment: It's my experience that questions about anything having to do with jailbreak development are highly likely to get voted down and/or closed.  It's unfortunate, but many in the community think either (a) that these questions are only applicable for a tiny number of developers, and thus are closeable as *too localized* ... which I think is the worst possible reason to close a question, or (b) that jailbreak developers are the same thing as software pirates, and thus deserve to have their questions censored as punishment.  It's silly, really.  I've upvoted you, and will vote to reopen if closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't yet jailbroken my iOS 6 device or run `class-dump` on all the iOS 6 frameworks, so I can't tell you if there's another *private API* to do exactly what you used to be able to do.

Your suggestion about inspecting the contents of app folders (e.g. `/var/mobile/Applications/*/*.app/`) and reading the iTunesMetadata.plist files sounds reasonable.  Reading each app's Info.plist would also give you the `CFBundleIdentifier`, which would normally at least contain the publisher's domain name (e.g. `com.mycompany.MyAppName`).

For apps that don't come from the app store (and don't have iTunesMetadata.plist), you could try another technique (in addition to reading Info.plist):

Cydia packages are maintained with `dpkg` utilities.  You can list all installed packages with the command `dpkg -l`.  You can invoke this command either with

```
system("dpkg -l >> /tmp/output.log 2>&1");
```

piping the output into a temporary file, or with `NSTask`.  `NSTask` is part of OS X APIs, and is not in the iOS public APIs.  But, if you add the NSTask.h header to your project yourself, you can certainly use it as a private API in a non-App Store app, to run a command and capture output programmatically.

At the command line, running `dpkg -l` would give you:

```
ii  libhide                                        2.1                                            Library to hide icons. If you are a developer wanting to use this library, code samples included in /usr/lib
ii  libxml2-lib                                    2.6.32-3                                       represents the library for libxml2
ii  lsof                                           33-4                                           shows what files programs have open
ii  lzma                                           4.32.7-4                                       slower, but better, compression algorithm
ii  make                                           3.81-2                                         dependency-based build environments
ii  mobilesubstrate                                0.9.3999.1                                     powerful code insertion platform
ri  ncurses                                        5.7-12                                         feature-complete terminal library
ii  network-cmds                                   307.0.1-6                                      arp, ifconfig, netstat, route, traceroute
```

so, your app could parse that output, to read package names from the second column.

Then, you could use the `apt-cache show` command to get the information from the package's DEBIAN/control file, which would have something like this:

```sh
iPhone-3G:~ root# apt-cache show sqlite3
Package: sqlite3
Version: 3.5.9-12
Architecture: iphoneos-arm
Maintainer: Jay Freeman (saurik) <saurik at saurik dot com>
Installed-Size: 348
Pre-Depends: dpkg (>= 1.14.25-8)
Depends: sqlite3-lib
Replaces: sqlite3 (<= 3.5.9-11)
Filename: debs/sqlite3_3.5.9-12_iphoneos-arm.deb
Size: 71928
MD5sum: 6d47c112692ac00af61bd84e3847aa42
Section: Data_Storage
Priority: standard
Description: embedded database used by iPhoneOS
Name: SQLite 3.x
Tag: purpose::library, role::developer
```

I know this is more work than just using `author` from `SBApplication`, but maybe it's good enough? Hopefully, some one else will chime in with another answer ...

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! I should have mentioned I'm using the AppList library, meaning getting package names is already done for me. But the rest will be useful!